# Initializing constructor elements with other constructor elements

Tags: c++, constructor

I have a class Foo that is initialized with a filename or null.  If there is a filename, the object db is initialized, otherwise it is null.  Either way, the object db_mon is initialized with the value of db, null or not.

Is this valid:

```
class Foo {
   Database *db;
   Database_monitor db_mon;

 public: 
   Foo(const char *db_file) : 
      db(db_file ? new db(db_file) : 0), db_mon(db)  {}
};
```

Comment: Initialization happens in the order the member variables are declared, so this seems fine to me. (My compiler even gives a warning if the order in the ctor initializer list does not match the order of declaration.)

Comment: Except for the typo `public` -> `public:`, this is valid. However I question the use of a pointer for an optional value. Prefer `std::optional`.

Comment: Or at least `std::unique_ptr<Database>` if it has to be a pointer. Also, you probably should delete, or implement with proper semantics, the copy and move operations if the class is self-referential like this.